# Adding notes permissions in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

We recently moved from Google to Sharepoint online and we are missing some features.

For example, we'd like to give users access to add note to a document without giving them edit permissions.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation would be a bit roundabout, but it is possible. Just create a "Notes" list, with a lookup column that references the document in question. Give users permissions to update the Notes list without giving them anything more than Read access to the documents library. You might then want to create a page that display metadata for the selected document, with any listed notes next to it.